# limit resources available to vscode notebooks

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote, jupyterhub

###### Is there an easy way to limit the resources available to vscode notebooks?

- For example I have a vscode notebook running some operations that consume all available cpus. So I want to limit the number of cpus it has access to